# App works on 3G connection but not work on Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android, connection

Hii am using php to make register user in mysql
But the problem... When i am using the 3G the work good 
But when i use the Wifi connection to post the username and password.. The app does not work and it wiating long time with no response.. 
This is my code

```
        void loginnn() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


    try {




        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://ssss.esy.es/register.php"); 

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", edts));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passs));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);



        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {



                    }
            });

        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")) { 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "faild", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

                    }
                });       } else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
            }}).start();
            }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it's solved... thank you

Comment: Nice, you should post the answer.

Comment: ok i will do after finishing my current project

Comment: hey, it would be great if you could share how you solved it, so it can help others :)

Comment: You should post the answer :)